# How to adapt an old PKG, driver and ROS wrapper to a new ROS distribution?

Tags: ros, driver, ros-hydro, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a Kuka youbot robot. The last updated version (by source) of the driver and ROS wrapper for this robot is Hydro. The most stable version of ROS is Kinetic. My question clearly is how I adapt the both hydro driver and ROS wrapper of this robot to Kinetic distribution? Is there any documentation for this purpose? I can not find any. Do I need to change CMakeLists.txt file?  I would appreciate it if you help me out.

Sincerely,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295888/how-to-adapt-an-old-pkg,-driver-and-ros-wrapper-to-a-new-ros-distribution?/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-07-01**:
If you provide a link to the package, we can have a look and see how much work is likely to be necessary.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2018-07-01**:
@Geoff
These are links to Youbot driver and its ROS wrapper. Thanks...
git clone http://github.com/youbot/youbot_driver.git -b hydro-devel
git clone http://github.com/youbot/youbot_driver_ros_interface.git -b hydro-devel

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-07-02**:
Latest stable ROS version is Melodic, not Kinetic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How much adaptation is needed depends on how many of the ROS APIs that package uses that have changed since Hydro.

If the package is still using `rosbuild`, you will need to change it to [use `catkin` instead](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild). This will include changing the `manifest.xml` file to a `package.xml` file, which includes changing the content a little.

After that, just start compiling it and fix any errors that arise. You probably won't have that many and they are not likely to be difficult to fix for the ROS API errors. Most problems will probably be in using other ROS packages depended on by your package.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-07-02**:
There are migration guides too:

- http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration
- http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration
- http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Migration